# Customize <input type="tel">

Tags: jquery, forms, html, input

Can you in any way change "+*#" when you using `<input type="tel">`? I know how to remove it so it just a blank button but i really need to have "," somewhere. Anyone knows if it's even possible?

Big thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern="[0-9]{10}"` attribute. Example [here](http://miketaylr.com/pres/html5/forms2.html)

Comment: Yes but there is no mask.